Efficient (vectorized) method of converting a Pandas DataFrame categorical column back into original values
After a quite lengthy series of operations on a Pandas DataFrame I find myself with a categorical type column.
This has been created as a result of a pandas.cut() operation.
I would like to convert the column back into "values" rather than the current categorical encoding.
This is how I am currently performing that conversion:
df['datetime_de_cat'] = (
    df['datetime_bin'].cat.codes.map(
        lambda code: df['datetime_bin'].cat.categories[code]
    )
)

Here's how this code works:
df['datetime_bin'] is a column of "binned" data values. This is created by pandas.cut(). The column is a categorical column, meaning that the data is encoded using integer values, and these integers can be used to map to the original data values.
df['datetime_bin'].cat.codes is a Pandas Series containing the above mentioned integer codes.
df['datetime_bin'].cat.categories is a datetime.DatetimeIndex. It can be used to map between the integer codes and original values.
There is some additional complexity introduced by the fact that some other intermediate operations are performed. For example, a Pandas cut() operation returns intervals, and I have already converted these by taking only the "right" part of the interval. (This changes an interval of two datetimes into a single datetime type.)
The code I am using, which is based on .map() is very slow. This is perhaps unsurprising. I suspect this operation is not particularly well vectorized. The lambda function will be interpreted by the Python interpreter at the interpreter level, rather than running as some more optimized C code.
Is there a way to accelerate this operation? It seems like converting a categorical column back into a regular non-categorical encoded column should be a fairly common operation with some faster implementation.

After some testing I have found that this works:
df['datetime_bin'].astype(str)

On the other hand:
df['datetime_bin'].astype(pandas.Timestamp)
df['datetime_bin'].astype(datetime)

do not work. These fail with the error class datetime.datetime is not understood (etc)
The conversion to string is very fast, which is not surprising, since this will be fully vectorized.
Is there a way to convert to a datetime type instead of str?
doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#regaining-original-data

Some information about the data I am working with
df.dtypes

datetime                    datetime64[ns, UTC]
datetime_bin                           category
datetime_bin_right                     category
datetime_bin_right_decat    datetime64[ns, UTC]
dtype: object

df['datetime_bin_right'] = df['datetime_bin'].map(lambda interval: interval.right)

# thanks to suggestion in the comments
# but: why doesn't this work using a `type` as the argument
# (eg: `datetime.datetime`, `pandas.Timestamp`)
# rather than `str`='datetime64[ns, UTC]'
df['datetime_bin_right_decat'] = df['datetime_bin_right'].astype('datetime64[ns, UTC]')


You can't trivially un-bin values narrowed into categorical columns unless you actually have unique bins for each value in your original dataset, in which case you've not actually binned anything but just enumerated values. You've omitted a large number of steps here likely to reduce the scope of this question, but it's possible it's been reduced too much. A bit of sample data to see what your values actually look like and what you're hoping to get as output would really go a long way to clarifying what you're looking to achieve.

If you're just looking to get the right bound of the bin as a usable DateTime can't you just take the output from cut and turn it into a datetime? Something like pd.cut(...).map(lambda i: i.right).astype('datetime64[ns]')

@HenryEcker Thanks for the suggestion. This does appear to work. Do you have any idea why if astype('datetime64[ns, UTC]') successfully converts a column from a categorical type to a datetime type, whereas neither of astype(datetime) or astype(pandas.Timestamp) does? (Both produce the exception described in the question above.)

I am not sure if this is really the right solution, but this does work.
df['new_col'] = df['datetime_bin'].astype(str) # not categorical
pandas.to_datetime(df['new_col']) # now datetime type col

This solution is less than ideal, since it requires a two-stage conversion process.
Converting straight to datetime does not work. (Below does not work.)
pandas.to_datetime(df['datetime_bin']) # still "categorical" - not sure why?


The working, two stage conversion, is still many orders of magnitude slower than the conversion to string: (The datetime conversion is slow.)
df['datetime_bin'].astype(str)

However also many orders of magnitude faster than the .map() solution.
